# Compile two projects on NDK w/ gradle, one of which depends on the other's binary

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm compiling a library in gradle like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {

        // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
        cmake {
            // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
            path "../../JRTPLIB/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

I need to compile another source, probably using cmake or any other tool, also inside gradle, that will link to the compiled object from the lib above (JRTPLIB).

The obvious way would be to include the source of the library above in the lib I want to use and just link, but I need to do it separatedly.

The other way would be to rely on the generated library object at `android/app/build/intermediates/cmake/...` but first, it's supposed to have a debug binary and a release one in this folder, making it more coplicated to link, and secondly, it's not an elegant solution.

So how to do it?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html

Comment: @Michael so I should make project 2 compile project 1 and then use its binary? What if I need both the binary of project 1 and project 2 on my android project?

Comment: I would suggest that you create a directory for each of your libraries, each with their own `CMakeLists.txt` which does `add_library` to build an .so file or whatever. Then in the parent directory you add the master `CMakeLists.txt` (the one that you point out in your gradle script) and have it do `add_subdirectory` for each of the libraries.

Comment: @Michael I added add_subdirectory, but when I run cmake on the main project, it just generates the make files of the subdirectories and then try to build the main project. How do I build the dependencies first?  I thought add_subdirectory would build them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example that accomplishes something like what I think you're trying to do.

Two libraries are being built and packaged into the app, where the second library depends on the first one. I chose to have lib1 and lib2 as part of the current project, but they could really be located anywhere.

**app/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/lib1)
add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/lib2)
```

---

**app/src/main/cpp/lib1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib1
             SHARED
             native-lib1.cpp )

target_include_directories(native-lib1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

---

**app/src/main/cpp/lib2/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib2
             SHARED
             native-lib2.cpp )

find_library(log-lib log)

# native-lib2 depends on log and native-lib1
target_link_libraries(native-lib2 ${log-lib} native-lib1)
```

---

**app/src/main/cpp/lib1/native-lib1.h**

```
#pragma once

int foo();
```

---

**app/src/main/cpp/lib1/native-lib1.cpp**

```
#include "native-lib1.h"

int foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

---

**app/src/main/cpp/lib2/native-lib2.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string>
#include "native-lib1.h"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_cmaketwolibs_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {

    // Call function from native-lib1
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,
                        "native-lib2", "Calling native-lib1\'s foo(): %d",
                        foo());

    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

Comment: thabk you so much. Very well written answer, wish I could give more points

Comment: just one question... what is `log`?

Comment: It's google's logging library that comes with the NDK. I'm using `__android_log_print`, hence why that library is necessary.

Comment: Awesome, learned a new thing, and the NDK example also will help a lot. Thanks!!!!